# Bitbucket Pipelines - is it possible to download additional file to project via curl?

Tags: maven, curl, spring-boot, download, bitbucket-pipelines

We have a separate build for the frontend and backend of the application, where we need to pull the dist build of frontend to backend project during the build. During the build the 'curl' cannot write to the desired location.
In detail, we are using SpringBoot as backend for serving Angular 2 frontend. So we need to pull the frontend files to src/main/resources/static folder.

```
image: maven:3.3.9
pipelines:
default:
- step:
    script: 
      - curl -s -L -v --user xxx:XXXX https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/apprentit/rent-it/downloads/release_latest.tar.gz -o src/main/resources/static/release_latest.tar.gz
      - tar -xf -C src/main/resources/static --directory src/main/resources/static release_latest.tar.gz
      - mvn package -X
```

As a result of this the build fails with output of CURL.

```
* Failed writing body (0 != 16360)
```

Note: I've tried the same with maven-exec-plugin, the result was the same. The solution works on local machine naturally.

Comment: At first glance, I don’t spot an error. But why don’t you remove the `-s` flag from the `curl` call to get more info on what’s happening? And: you are sure `src/main/resources/static` exists`? I’m asking because that looks like a path that could be ignored in VCS and therefore be missing.

Answer (score 0):

I would try running these commands from a local `docker run` of the image you're specifying (`maven:3.3.9`). I found that the most helpful way to debug things that were behaving differently in Pipelines vs. in my local environment.

To your specific question yes, you can download external content from the Pipeline run. I have a Pipeline that clones other repos from BitBucket via HTTP into the running container.